# kubernetes logout after oauth2_proxy and keycloak authentication

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-dashboard, oauth2-proxy

I am facing an issue with the kubernetes dashboard after authenticating using keycloak and oauth2_proxy.

The authentication part works fine and I added the rbac in k8s to define different levels of access.

The problem there is no logout from the kubernetes dashboard after logging in.

Here is my oauth2_proxy config:

```
            - '--http-address=0.0.0.0:4180'
            - '--email-domain=test.com'
            - '--provider=keycloak-oidc'
            - '--client-id=kubernetes'
            - '--client-secret=****************'
            - '--cookie-secret="******************"'
            - >-
              --redirect-url=https://oauth2-proxy.test.com/oauth2/callback
            - >-
              --oidc-issuer-url=https://keycloak.test.com/auth/realms/myRealm
            - '--scope=openid email profile groups'
            - '--show-debug-on-error=true'
            - '--pass-access-token=true'
            - '--pass-authorization-header=true'            
            - '--set-authorization-header=true'
            - '--skip-jwt-bearer-tokens=true'
            - '--skip-provider-button=false'
```

For the keycloak part I have added a front-channel logout url as follow
https://oauth2-proxy.test.com/oauth2/sign_out

When I'm connected to the dashboard if I click my user icon instead of logout I get "connected with an auth header"

I tried to add a config to the Ouath2_proxy by adding
--logout-url=https://oauth2-proxy.test.com/oauth2/sign_out but there is no such flag in ouath2_proxy configuration

What can I do to have the logout in the dashboard.